# Pre populated radio button in php

Tags: php, radio-button

I have radio buttons for Yes and No and want to pre-populate them from a value in a mysql database. I am able to show the radio buttons but they always show the Yes checked even when the returned value is No. I am also not able to change the pre-populated value eg Yes to No.

```
<input  type="radio" id="etag" name="etag" value="Yes" <?php echo ($d_etag == 'Yes') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />Yes
<input  type="radio" id="etag" name="etag" value="No" <?php echo ($d_etag == 'No') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />No
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem by adding your **complete** code. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't use the same `id` attribute for both buttons, IDs must be unique. Try changing them to `id="etag_yes"` and `id="etag_no"` respectively. Other than that, I don't see any issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note : **id = should b unique** as mentioned by [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil) in his comments

This is how you can achieve ur task!

```
<input  type="radio" id="etag_1" name="etag" value="Yes" <?php echo ($d_etag == 'Yes') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />Yes
<input  type="radio" id="etag_2" name="etag" value="No" <?php echo ($d_etag == 'No') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />No
```

> To find out Which **Radio button is clicked** use

```
$("input:radio[name=etag]").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
});
```

or try this

```
$('input:radio[name=etag]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you `var_dump($d_etag);` and check the data type of that variable. it should be a string with Case-sensitive.

Can you try this:

```
<input  type="radio" id="etagYes" name="etag" value="Yes" <?php echo ($d_etag == 'Yes') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />Yes
<input  type="radio" id="etagNo" name="etag" value="No" <?php echo ($d_etag == 'Yes') ? '' : 'checked="checked"'; ?> />No
```